# Python 2.7: Removing a dict in a list if a key is missing or empty

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, filtering

The list in question looks something like this, just a list of Blogs with any Posts if applicable:

```
blogs = {
            {
             'id': 1, 
             'title': 'Foodies', 
             'posts': {
                  { 'id': 28, 'title': 'Sourdough Bread starter', 'blog_id': 1},
                  { 'id': 64, 'title': 'How to make brioche in under 4 hours', 'blog_id': 1}
                 }
            },{
                'id': 2, 
                'title': 'Southern Meals', 
                'posts': {}
            },{
               'id': 3, 
               'title': 'Vegomamma'
            },{
               'id': 4, 
               'title': 'Culinare'
            }
        }
```

I only want the Blogs with Posts, so I'm trying to reduce the list so that I would only get the first dict returned.

Here's what I tried, which threw the error: 
"'dict' object has no attribute 'posts'"

Which I understand, but I am trying to remove dicts without that attribute.

```
for b in blogs:
    if "posts" not in b or b.posts.count() == 0:
        blogs.remove(b)
```

Why does this fail? It seemed like a pretty simple solution, and I've used it before.

This app is built in Python and Angular, so I could do the filtering in Angular, but I'd rather take care of it in Python.

**EDIT** Added the exact error message.

Comment: Please show us the error it throws so it's easier to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`

Comment: It's `b['posts'].count()` .....

Comment: Probably the most external { } should be [ ] to create an actual list

Comment: Thanks, that's what I meant to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off all your data structure is not a valid python object. You have a set contain dictionaries that are not hashable objects (will raise `TypeError`). Based on your question body It seems that it's a list. Secondly, you don't need to check the existence of `posts` within the dictionary you can jsut use `dict.get()` within a list comprehension. `get` method returns None if the key is missing:

```
In [20]: [b for b in blogs if b.get('posts')]
Out[20]: 
[{'posts': [{'id': 28, 'title': 'Sourdough Bread starter', 'blog_id': 1},
   {'id': 64, 'title': 'How to make brioche in under 4 hours', 'blog_id': 1}],
  'id': 1,
  'title': 'Foodies'}]
```

Also, note that since the `post` is supposed to be an iterable the validation check will failed if it's empty (it evaluated as False). That's why I just used `if b.get('posts')`.

Comment: Thanks! This is much more elegant than the answer I got to work.